# How to design a TextBox which shows line number int he Left or Right Side?

Tags: wpf

Is there any control available which shows line number in Textbox either in the left side or right side? If not how to approach to create a control like that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you're not the first one who came across this kind of question.

So here are a few links you may find helpful:

[WPF RichTextBox to create editor with line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567404/wpf-richtextbox-to-create-editor-with-line-numbers)

http://www.aqistar.com/

Comment: UPDATE: aquistar site is no more.

Answer (score 2):

For wpf I have done this by adding the following to the xaml:-

```
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxLineNumbers" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="18" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right" Text="" Foreground="#50000000" Background="Transparent" Margin="0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"/>
        <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="TextBox_ScrollChanged"  x:Name="TextBoxResult" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Left" Text="" Foreground="Black" Background="Transparent" Margin="60,0,0,0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"/>
    </Grid>
```

And to the xaml.cs file:-

```
    private void SetUpLines(string data)
    {
        int noLines = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) ? 0 : data.Split('\n').Length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= noLines; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(i.ToString());
        }

        TextBoxLineNumbers.Text = sb.ToString();
        TextBoxResult.Text = data??"";
    }

    private void TextBox_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxLineNumbers.ScrollToVerticalOffset(TextBoxResult.VerticalOffset);
    }
```

Call SetUpLines to populate the TextBox.  Note this uses a fixed size font and doesn't do line wrapping, I did not want that. I know this is an old question but I didn't see a simple answer anywhere else.