# Show LineNumbers from the RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, line-numbers

I found an example, how to show the LineNumbers from a `RichTextBox` in Windows Forms.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38858/Line-Numbers-for-RichText-Control-in-C

Have somebody an example for it in **WPF**?

Edit:

Does someone have work with AvalonEdit, because he wanted to show LineNumbers in his Programm and can help me by my Problem.

Comment: Have you considered any of the options mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/567404/650012) SO question? Aqistar no longer seems to be an alternative (link is dead), but [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) might be a feasible alternative?

Comment: Do you want to follow MVVM for this or without MVVM?,

Comment: You may need to make your own custom textbox and other things to make this happen.

Comment: @Faisal Hafeez without MVVM.

Answer (score 10):

I thought just to add a simple solution...

`Avalon` ([Download](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit)) has been mentioned, here is how to do row lines with it:

```
<avalon:TextEditor ShowLineNumbers="True" Width="500" Height="500"
                    Text="some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; some more test&#10; ">
</avalon:TextEditor>
```

It's a very powerful editor - and I've been doing a lot with it and in production (custom language compilers etc.). It's free so it has its 'quirks' but it's allowing you to do pretty much anything you need. I'm not sure which formatted text are you talking about - but anything you need can be done, and in not too many lines of code, if you know how, where to inject (you can add your own generators, transformers, pretty much any visuals, code completition etc. - and I have no vested interest in it:)

#### Edit

Small sample for syntax highlighting:

```
<avalon:TextEditor 
  ShowLineNumbers="True" 
  SyntaxHighlighting="C#" Width="500" Height="500"
  Text="void Test(int id, string name)&#10;{&#10;&#09;name = name + id.ToString();}" />
```

Supported is `"XmlDoc", "C#", "JavaScript", "HTML", "ASP/XHTML", "Boo", "Coco", "CSS", "C+", "Java", "Patch", "PHP", "TeX", "VBNET", "XML"` as far as I can tell from the code.

If you'd like to implement your own custom `syntax highlighting` (Avalon editor is highly extendable - for details see that [code project article mentioned](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor))...

You'd need to define your own `IHighlightingDefinition`, then register that with the `HighlightingManager` from the code - and then add some more things to complement. But that's a long story on its own.

Comment: Does Avalon Edit use FlowDocument or TextBlock and can you show me where I can find the function for the LineNumbers? Can you show me a test application where you use the LineNumbers-function of Avalon

Comment: Karl, that above is the test app - I used it and checked it out and it works just 'as is'. It has its own `TextView` and its own system (unrelated to RichTextBox). You need to get used to its inner-workings (it's a 3rd party control), otherwise works fine and you can do all you need.

Comment: I have test it in my software. Can you say me how I change the SyntaxHighlighting with C#-Code, when i have only the name of the Syntax as string?

Comment: I edited in - you can also have your own syntax etc. - but as I said out of the scope of this one. I hope you'll be satisfied with this answer :). If you need some more I'd suggest to open a new question and I'll be glad to help you out, just put up smaller, targeted questions. Cheers.

Comment: Really great editor. Although I'm struggling learning it, but it surely will be a great choice, even the ultimate one. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a custom template for your TextBox; the following answer may help you:

[Visible line count of a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105982/visible-line-count-of-a-textblock)

**Update**

---

Changing the answer to get works as OP expected.

```
<Style x:Key="Local_TextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Designer,

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uiTextBox, Path=(local:AttachedProperties.BindableLineCount)}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="uiTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" local:AttachedProperties.HasBindableLineCount="True"
            AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding LongText}" Style="{StaticResource Local_TextBox}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Attached property,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Cmsn.Software.Tutorials.numberedTextBox
{
    public class AttachedProperties
    {
        #region BindableLineCount AttachedProperty
        public static string GetBindableLineCount(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableLineCountProperty);
        }

        public static void SetBindableLineCount(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(BindableLineCountProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BindableLineCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableLineCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BindableLineCount",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(AttachedProperties),
            new UIPropertyMetadata("1"));

        #endregion // BindableLineCount AttachedProperty

        #region HasBindableLineCount AttachedProperty
        public static bool GetHasBindableLineCount(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(HasBindableLineCountProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHasBindableLineCount(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HasBindableLineCountProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasBindableLineCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBindableLineCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "HasBindableLineCount",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(AttachedProperties),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                false,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHasBindableLineCountChanged)));

        private static void OnHasBindableLineCountChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)o;
            if ((e.NewValue as bool?) == true)
            {
                textBox.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(box_SizeChanged);
                textBox.SetValue(BindableLineCountProperty, textBox.LineCount.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.SizeChanged -= new SizeChangedEventHandler(box_SizeChanged);
            }
        }

        static void box_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            string x = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < textBox.LineCount; i++)
            {
                x += i + 1 + "\n";
            }
            textBox.SetValue(BindableLineCountProperty, x);
        }
        #endregion // HasBindableLineCount AttachedProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because the OP wan't just count the lines, but displaying the line number on the RichEdit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but I cant use your soulution, because i have to load a FlowDocument with formated Text in the richTextBox

Comment: Hope Downvoter saw the @Karl_Schuhmann's comment saying that it works.

Comment: change the listener to `textBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(box_SizeChanged);`

Answer (score 2):

[ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) is a good component to try.  It's the .NET version of Scintilla which is a key component in the [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) editor (among others).  I don't know how it compares to AvalonEdit, but I found it fairly easy to implement in my code and it has the feature you require (and many more).

Once you've [installed the component](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation) and added it to your form, you can [show line numbers](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToLineNumber) by going to the properties of the control and setting Margins>Margin0>Width.  You can also set this programmatically:

```
scintilla1.Margins.Margin0.Width = 20;
```

You might find the [ScintillaNet documentation](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/documentation) useful if you plan to take this route - I found it really helpful when I started.

Comment: can you show me an example from it? I can't find the LineNumber Function there.

Comment: I've added some more details on line numbers and some documentation links above. Hope it helps!

Comment: I followed the steps, but the controls do not appear in my `toolbox`

Comment: @Karl My fault, make sure you follow the steps for _Configuring the Search Path_ too.  That whole page is pretty important, especially those two sections.  I'll update my answer for clarity.

Comment: I find it but i can't use them. Here: [link](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenannt96nmfih1kw.png) #Edit: I Use .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: @Karl Ah, I had that problem too - make sure you're in the Form Designer when you're trying to use it.  (.NET 4 too, should be fine)

Comment: I know why it doesnt Work, because I use WPF, not WinForms

Comment: That would be problematic - sorry I didn't notice the WPF requirement.  I did notice [this](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/discussions/224945) post which may help, but it looks like AvalonEdit may be your best option in this case.

Comment: But I think, that I can do it with Scintilla, because in the Source, there is a solution in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The best [example you can find is in AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit). There is lot more anyway that just line numbering, but you can study how it is done, code is very clear. A staring point to see what we are talking about can be [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor).

Comment: I know AvalonEdit, but i have to load a formated text in my richtextbox. I cant use the highlighting. Can you show me any example for it? @FelicePollano

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35413/CodeBox-An-Extended-and-Improved-Version-of-the) that shows a detailed approach to implementing line numbers and a handful of other nice code editing features in a TextBox control. If you don't care about how it's built, just download the sample file and use the included dll that contains the compiled control.