# LineNumbers in RichTextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, line-numbers

How to get linenumbers in RichtextBox in WPF. I did take a look at the AvalonEdit in codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor. However, it looks quite complicated just for the feature I am looking at. I just need to display linenumbers in RichTextBox which is the content of a TabControl. Any piece of code that will get me started will be great.

Comment: Why don't you want to use AvalonEdit?

Comment: Take a look at question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610940/show-linenumbers-from-the-richtextbox-in-wpf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show LineNumbers from the RichTextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610940/show-linenumbers-from-the-richtextbox-in-wpf)